# VHDL Type of xxx is incompatible with type of xxx

Tags: types, casting, vhdl

Ich have two different types:

```
type signal_4bit_t is
record
   signals_v      : STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
end record;

 type signal_8bit_t is
record
   signals_v      : STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
end record;
```

and I create two Arrays:

```
 type Array_signal_4bit_t   is array (0 to 2) of signal_4bit_t;
 type Array_signal_8bit_t   is array (0 to 2) of signal_8bit_t;
```

and one entity uses the 4bit Array as Input:

```
entity test_input is
    Port ( 
           hx_i      : in  Array_signal_4bit_t;
           lx_i      : in  Array_signal_4bit_t;
          );
end test;
```

and another uses the 8bit Array as Output:

```
entity test_ouput is
    Port ( 
           out_o      : out Array_signal_8bit_t
          );
end test;
```

For the Conncetion between the two components I use the signal:

```
signal tets_out_to_test_in   : Array_signal_8bit_t;
```

The Instantation looks like this:

```
in: test_input 
    Port Map ( 
           hx_i  =>    tets_out_to_test_in(7 downto 4),
           lx_i  =>    tets_out_to_test_in(3 downto 0)
          );

out: test_out 
    Port Map ( 
           out_o  =>    tets_out_to_test_in
          );
```

Now I get the error "Type of hx_i is incompatible with type of tets_out_to_test_in. I see that Array_signal_4bit_t is different to Array_signal_8bit_t, but is there a "easy" way to fix this problem without chanching my entites? Or any idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Your code snippets don't comprise a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), there are  also syntax errors present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a Minimum, Verifiable and Complete example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package somepack is
    type signal_4bit_t is
    record
       signals_v      : std_ulogic_vector (3 downto 0);
    end record;

     type signal_8bit_t is
    record
       signals_v      : std_ulogic_vector (7 downto 0);
    end record;
    type array_signal_4bit_t   is array (0 to 2) of signal_4bit_t;
    type array_signal_8bit_t   is array (0 to 2) of signal_8bit_t;
end package;

use work.somepack.all;
entity test_input is
    port ( 
           hx_i      : in  array_signal_4bit_t;
           lx_i      : in  array_signal_4bit_t
         );
end test_input;

architecture foo of test_input is
begin
end architecture;

use work.somepack.all;
entity test_output is
    port ( 
           out_o      : out array_signal_8bit_t
         );
end test_output;

architecture foo of test_output is
begin
end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.somepack.all;

entity sometestbench is
end entity;

architecture foo of sometestbench is
    signal tets_out_to_test_in: array_signal_8bit_t;
    component test_input is
        port (
            hx_i: in  array_signal_4bit_t;
            lx_i: in  array_signal_4bit_t
        );
    end component;
    component test_output is
        port (
           out_o      : out array_signal_8bit_t        
        );
    end component;    

    signal hx_i_high: array_signal_4bit_t;
    signal lx_i_low:  array_signal_4bit_t;

begin

    hx_i_high(0).signals_v <= tets_out_to_test_in(0).signals_v(7 downto 4);
    hx_i_high(1).signals_v <= tets_out_to_test_in(1).signals_v(7 downto 4);
    hx_i_high(2).signals_v <= tets_out_to_test_in(2).signals_v(7 downto 4);
    lx_i_low(0).signals_v  <= tets_out_to_test_in(0).signals_v(3 downto 0);
    lx_i_low(1).signals_v  <= tets_out_to_test_in(1).signals_v(3 downto 0);
    lx_i_low(2).signals_v  <= tets_out_to_test_in(2).signals_v(3 downto 0);                

label_in: test_input 
    port map ( 
          --  hx_i  =>    tets_out_to_test_in(7 downto 4),
          hx_i => hx_i_high,
          --lx_i  =>    tets_out_to_test_in(3 downto 0)
          lx_i => lx_i_low
    );


label_out: test_output 
    port map ( 
           out_o  =>    tets_out_to_test_in
          );    
end architecture;
```

There were various punctuation issues and spelling mismatches, in and out can't be used as identifiers (labels) they're reserved words.  The component test_out should be test_output,...

There's also a bit more direct, constructing an array_signal_4bit_t type from elements extracted from the array_signal_8bit_t type:

```
    hx_i_high <= array_signal_4bit_t'(
               0 => (signals_v => tets_out_to_test_in(0).signals_v(7 downto 4)),
               1 => (signals_v => tets_out_to_test_in(1).signals_v(7 downto 4)),
               2 => (signals_v => tets_out_to_test_in(2).signals_v(7 downto 4))
               );

    lx_i_low <= array_signal_4bit_t'(
               0 => (signals_v => tets_out_to_test_in(0).signals_v(3 downto 0)),
               1 => (signals_v => tets_out_to_test_in(1).signals_v(3 downto 0)),
               2 => (signals_v => tets_out_to_test_in(2).signals_v(3 downto 0))
               );
```

You can't do this in the actual in the association list because the expression operand of the qualified expressions must be globally static (historically *(-1993)* and likely for synthesis still). (In IEEE Std 1076-2008, 6.5.6.3 Port clauses, para 6):

> If the actual part of a given association element for a formal port of a block is the reserved word inertial followed by an expression, **or is an expression that is not globally static**, then the given association element is equivalent to association of the port with an anonymous signal implicitly declared in the declarative region that immediately encloses the block. The signal has the same subtype as the formal port and is the target of an implicit concurrent signal assignment statement of the form

```
anonymous <= E;
```

> where E is the expression in the actual part of the given association element. The concurrent signal
>   assignment statement occurs in the same statement part as the block.

The above examples also make the point you don't have to have a loop.

This MVCe analyzes, elaborates and simulates (while doing nothing particularly interesting).

A slightly different architecture uses a procedure:

```
architecture fie of sometestbench is
    signal tets_out_to_test_in: array_signal_8bit_t;
    component test_input is
        port (
            hx_i: in  array_signal_4bit_t;
            lx_i: in  array_signal_4bit_t
        );
    end component;
    component test_output is
        port (
           out_o      : out array_signal_8bit_t        
        );
    end component;    

    signal hx_i_high: array_signal_4bit_t;
    signal lx_i_low:  array_signal_4bit_t;

    procedure slice_array_signal_8bit (
            signal input:   in  array_signal_8bit_t; 
            signal low:     out array_signal_4bit_t;
            signal high:    out array_signal_4bit_t
    ) is
    begin
        for i in array_signal_4bit_t'range loop
            high(i).signals_v <= input(i).signals_v(7 downto 4);
            low(i).signals_v  <= input(i).signals_v(3 downto 0);
        end loop;
    end procedure;

begin

BREAKOUT: 
slice_array_signal_8bit ( tets_out_to_test_in, hx_i_high, lx_i_low);             

label_in: test_input 
    port map ( 
          hx_i => hx_i_high,
          lx_i => lx_i_low
    );


label_out: test_output 
    port map ( 
           out_o  =>    tets_out_to_test_in
          );    
end architecture;
```

Which also tells us how to use a process statement:

```
architecture foe of sometestbench is
    signal tets_out_to_test_in: array_signal_8bit_t;
    component test_input is
        port (
            hx_i: in  array_signal_4bit_t;
            lx_i: in  array_signal_4bit_t
        );
    end component;
    component test_output is
        port (
           out_o      : out array_signal_8bit_t        
        );
    end component;    

    signal hx_i_high: array_signal_4bit_t;
    signal lx_i_low:  array_signal_4bit_t;

begin

BREAKOUT: 
    process (tets_out_to_test_in)
    begin
        for i in array_signal_4bit_t'range loop
            hx_i_high(i).signals_v <= tets_out_to_test_in(i).signals_v(7 downto 4);
            lx_i_low(i).signals_v  <= tets_out_to_test_in(i).signals_v(3 downto 0);
        end loop;
    end process;          

label_in: test_input 
    port map ( 
          hx_i => hx_i_high,
          lx_i => lx_i_low
    );


label_out: test_output 
    port map ( 
           out_o  =>    tets_out_to_test_in
          );    
end architecture;
```

And finally, the simplest way:

```
architecture fum of sometestbench is
    signal tets_out_to_test_in: array_signal_8bit_t;
    component test_input is
        port (
            hx_i: in  array_signal_4bit_t;
            lx_i: in  array_signal_4bit_t
        );
    end component;
    component test_output is
        port (
           out_o      : out array_signal_8bit_t
        );
    end component;
begin

label_in: test_input
    port map (
          hx_i(0).signals_v => tets_out_to_test_in(0).signals_v(7 downto 4),
          hx_i(1).signals_v => tets_out_to_test_in(1).signals_v(7 downto 4),
          hx_i(2).signals_v => tets_out_to_test_in(2).signals_v(7 downto 4),
          lx_i(0).signals_v => tets_out_to_test_in(0).signals_v(3 downto 0),
          lx_i(1).signals_v => tets_out_to_test_in(1).signals_v(3 downto 0),
          lx_i(2).signals_v => tets_out_to_test_in(2).signals_v(3 downto 0)
    );

label_out: test_output
    port map (
           out_o  =>    tets_out_to_test_in
          );
end architecture;
```

We get to map elements of formal's composite type to actual elements individually in a port association list. And this form should be synthesis eligible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hints. Afterwards i got the problem when I have two array_signal_4bit_t as outputs and i must connect them with a array_signal_8bit_t. I solved it with your hint and i used a procedure for it. And your simplest I dont can you use, because the size of the array should be dynamic and set it by an generic.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has 2 problems:

1. You have to address the members of the records to access the inner std_ulogic_vectors.
2. You have to loop over every index of vector `test_out_to_test_in` to assign it to the resulting vector. This can be done by a generate statement or a process (not so nice solution) or a function (nice solution).

signals:

```
signal test_out_to_test_in   : Array_signal_8bit_t;
signal test_in_lo            : Array_signal_4bit_t;
signal test_in_hi            : Array_signal_4bit_t;
```

instances:

```
out: test_out 
  Port Map ( 
    out_o  =>  test_out_to_test_in
  );

gen : for i in test_out_to_test_in'range generate
  test_in_lo(i).signals_v   <= test_out_to_test_in(i).signals_v(3 downto 0);
  test_in_hi(i).signals_v   <= test_out_to_test_in(i).signals_v(7 downto 4);
end generate;

in: test_input 
  Port Map ( 
    hx_i  =>    test_in_hi,
    lx_i  =>    test_in_lo
  );
```

Are you sure, you want to used records, not even subtypes?

**Edit 1:**

If you just want to create a new type which is a std_ulogic_vector of 4 bits than you can use a subtype:

```
subtype signal_4bit_t is STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
subtype signal_8bit_t is STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
```

In most cases it's more flexible to leave array types unconstrained:

```
type Array_signal_4bit_t is array (NATURAL range <>) of signal_4bit_t;
type Array_signal_8bit_t is array (NATURAL range <>) of signal_8bit_t;
```

Now your assignment code would look like this:

```
signal test_out_to_test_in   : Array_signal_8bit_t(0 to 2);
signal test_in_lo            : Array_signal_4bit_t(0 to 2);
signal test_in_hi            : Array_signal_4bit_t(0 to 2);

out: test_out 
  Port Map ( 
    out_o  =>  test_out_to_test_in
  );

gen : for i in test_out_to_test_in'range generate
  test_in_lo(i)   <= test_out_to_test_in(i)(3 downto 0);
  test_in_hi(i)   <= test_out_to_test_in(i)(7 downto 4);
end generate;

in: test_input 
  Port Map ( 
    hx_i  =>    test_in_hi,
    lx_i  =>    test_in_lo
  );
```

**Edit 2:**

You can hide the conversion code, which is now using a generate statement, by writing a function:

```
function to_4bit_hi(value : Array_signal_8bit_t) return Array_signal_4bit_t is
  variable Result : Array_signal_4bit_t;
begin
  for i in value'range loop
    Result(i) <= value(i)(7 downto 4);
  end loop;
  return Result;
end function;
```

You will need a second function for `3 downto 0` or you path the offset as a parameter to the function. Using functions in port maps is not supported by every tool, so you will still need two extra signals.

```
signal test_out_to_test_in   : Array_signal_8bit_t(0 to 2);
signal test_in_lo            : Array_signal_4bit_t(0 to 2);
signal test_in_hi            : Array_signal_4bit_t(0 to 2);

out: test_out 
  Port Map ( 
    out_o  =>  test_out_to_test_in
  );

test_in_lo   <= to_4bit_lo(test_out_to_test_in);
test_in_hi   <= to_4bit_hi(test_out_to_test_in);

in: test_input 
  Port Map ( 
    hx_i  =>    test_in_hi,
    lx_i  =>    test_in_lo
  );
```

If you are interested in more vector manipulation functions and procedures have a look into this package: https://code.google.com/p/picoblaze-library/source/browse/vhdl/lib_PoC/vectors.vhdl?name=release

Comment: First of all thank. I tried your solution and it seems to work. Sorray i am relativ new to VHDL. So could you pleas tell me how I here can use subtypes or create a function?

Comment: @GerdMüller Added 2 more examples for subtype and function usage.

Comment: Thanks for the function. I implemeted it in my code and it works!